# What is the latest version of SSMS on 32 bits? (SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need the latest version of SSMS on 32 bits.

I found that current version 17.x works only on 64 bits.

Also I found a list of previouos versions but cannot tell which one is for 32 bits:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms#previous-ssms-releases

Please help!

Comment: Look for the first version of SQL Server itself that is 64bit only: it will be the previous version (SSMS is still 32bit, its changelog will not help you).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (read SSMS as SSRS :-)). All versions of SSMS are 32bit (this will not change until Visual Studio goes 64bit).

Comment: Richard, the latest version of SSMS (17.2) is 64 bit only

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SQL Server 2014 includes a 32 bit version of Management Studio. It can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 - read the Details section to choose which of downloads you need, click Download and then click the relevant file. MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe seems like a good prospect.

Alternatively, SQL Server 2012 also includes a 32 bit version of SSMS. That version of SSMS can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True , click Download and then get the SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe file.

As your question notes, the latest version of SSMS is 64 bit only.

Comment: they took these links down

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've checked the links and they are working. I've expanded the answer text a little to make it clearer how to download the installers from the links.

Comment: Today, I installed SQL Server Management studio 18.3.1, and the program itself appears to be 32-bit, verified by the 7-zip method, given in [How to check if an EXE is 32-bit or 64-bit on Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/check-exe-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-10/), reporting `CPU = x86` and it is installed in C:\Program Files (x86).

Comment: @R.Schreurs, seriously. It states in the install criteria on the very same page that you get 18.3.1 this: 

`Supported operating systems (SSMS 18.3.1)
 This release of SSMS supports the following 64-bit platforms when used with 
 the latest available service pack: 

Windows 10 (64-bit) * Windows 8.1 (64-bit) Windows Server 2019 (64-bit) Windows Server 2016 (64-bit) * Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit) Windows Server 2012 (64-bit) Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)`

Comment: @IamBatman, my comment wasn’t on the supported OS, but on the executable. I found it surprising that Mircosoft requires a 64-bit OS, while the executable itself is 32-bit.

Comment: @R.Schreurs I have a 32-bit system and 18.3.1 refuses to install.  I had to install SSMS 2016.  *shrugs*

Comment: @IamBatman, yes, I know. That's the reason I came here in the first place and why this question was asked at all. My comment was a comment in its own right and is not to be treated as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Management Studio Release 16.5.3 install on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit succeeded.

Downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946 found at [SQL Server Management Studio - Changelog (SSMS) section SSMS 16.5.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2016#downloadssdtmediadownloadpng-ssms-1653httpsgomicrosoftcomfwlinklinkid840946)

Answer (score 0):

For latest version, head to [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

For previous SSMS releases, head to [Previous SSMS releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-ssms-releases)

Bonus: [Direct download link of latest version](https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup)

Comment: Well here I am folks, it's 2022, and Visual Studio 2022 is 64-bit.....

.... and SSMS is still 32 bit

How quaint